# Quoting a File Name the Way bash Does?

Tags: bash, shell

Imagine i have file with this name:

```
My crazy file's "quoting" problem!.txt
```

If I am working in bash interactively, with TAB, bash will quote the file for me to something like this:

```
My\ crazy\ file\'s\ \"quoting\"\ problem\!.txt
```

My question is if I have that file name in a text file or saved in a variable inside a script, is there a utility to print the filename in the same quoted format?  For example, if i had a text file with a bunch of file names and I wanted to print them out in the same (or at least similar functionally) way bash quotes.

I realize that file names could be massaged with sed, regexps, etc. but I was hoping to avoid the work of thinking up all the rules.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with bash's `printf` using the `%q` format conversion:

```
$ file='My crazy file'"'"'s "quoting" problem!.txt'
$ printf "%q\n" "$file"
My\ crazy\ file\'s\ \"quoting\"\ problem\!.txt
```

Having said that, you shouldn't really need to do that, since it would mostly be useful for use in `eval`, for example, and you should probably look for an alternative. Still, if you need it, there it is.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of something like

```
echo $yourvariable | sed 's/\\//g' | sed 's/^/"/g' | sed 's/$/"/g'
```

You may save modify/enhance this and save in your $PATH. Then you can freely access this where you have those unusual file names/string/etc;

Comment: or `echo $yourvariable | sed 's/\\//g;y/^$/""/'`

Comment: @Cyrus Yes we can (we should in a serious script) do like that. I just wanted to decompose the step for more verbosity for the reader.